# Add a custom class to a project in webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

im new in asp.net and im trying to add a custom class to my proyect.

i created a file called Test.cs

```
public class Test
{
  public string sayHello()
  {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

and in my Default.cshtml :

```
Test example = new Test();
@example.sayHello();
```

But i get a error trying to load Test class... I need to include something with "using"? I need to compile with visual studio to create custom classes? or i miss something?

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new dir named "App_Code" in the root of your site and move your Test.cs in it.

Then, this Default.cshtml works:

```
@{
    Test example = new Test(); 
    var message = example.sayHello(); 

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>@message</p>
    </body>
</html>
```